# Best way to store and search large text data in Android

Tags: android, xml, database, sqlite

I am developing a constitution app for Android. I want to know what is the best way to store the large text data. The features I will want is for it to be searchable and fast. If am to use sqlite3, how am supposed to create the file and where do I upload it into the app, if am to use XML to store it, will it be searchable? Speed will matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) sqlite can create [FTS (Full Text Search) tables](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1). Basically it's a table with a builtin index on every word. It allows you to find data with queries like

```
SELECT * FROM chapter WHERE chapter MATCH 'someword'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM chapter WHERE chapter MATCH 'someword NEAR/6 otherword'
```

meaning 'where someword and otherword are separated by less than 6 words'.

2) As for how to include the database in you application, I think you have 2 options :

- Build the database beforehand (e.g. using [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html), which has builtin sqlite bindings) and include it in your application's assets.
- Include text file(s) assets and create the database on first launch.

Comment: thanks you pointed me in the right direction, and am using [Jeff Gilfelt's](https://github.com/jgilfelt) [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) Library

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the text file in lines and store the lines in a sqlite database.

You can also add data related to the lines organizing them in chapters, associating related topics, tags, etc...

Then you can query the text by "full scanning" the text table. "select line_number from table where line like "%word%";

Based on the lines meeting the search, you could bring up the corresponding page or chapter.

This is a simple example, you can build your app to generate more fine tuned queries.

But this approach should have a better cost/benefit ratio considering the search time and what to do with what you found after searching.